# Identify 4 Consecutive Observations

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I am very new to SAS and would very much appreciate some guidance. I have created a multi-thousand observation dataset within which I need to identify the occurrence of 4 consecutive, monthly instances - by two fields (person, clerk). That is: "Clerks that connected with Persons 4 months consecutively, over a period of 13 months"

In preparation, I have assigned each year-month (i.e. 2016.01, 2019.02) an INT value indicative of its place within the 13 month time span I care about.

Here is a mock sample:

```
PersonID    ClerkID monthINT
123456          789415  1
123456          789415  2
123456          789415  3
123456          789415  4
123456          789415  6
123456          789415  8
123456          789415  10
123456          789415  11
123456          789415  12
123456          789415  13
```

Comment: Hint:  `data` step with `retain`.

Comment: You don't indicate what you want as the output. The examples here should give you a good idea of what you need, but you can also look at the DIF() or INTCK() functions if you have a date variable.

Comment: Thank you for looking and apologies for not including details for a desired result. As my goal is qualify records based upon 4 consecutive criteria, I would want to flag these records accordingly. The fourth and last records in my mock dataset, for example, depict those meeting the criteria: 4 consecutive instances. A "Result" field, showing a "Y" indicator would absolutely suffice.

Comment: How do you treat multiple matches ? id clerk 1 connected with person 1 every month of the 13 months ?

Comment: The dataset is comprised of multiple PersonIDs matched to multiple ClerkIDs over a 13 month period. Each PersonID-ClerkID match is unique, by month. I have investigated LEAD and LAG functions as means of solution.

Comment: I know that is must be a matter of first sorting the dataset and then iterating through it, comparing each record to the one immediately adjacent.

Comment: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-create-an-enumeration-variable-by-groups/

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a running count. Reset the count when you hit a new id or hit a gap.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  by PersonID ClerkID monthINT ;
  if monthint-1=lag(monthint) and not first.clerkid then run_length+1;
  else run_length=1;
  flag = run_length >= 4;
run;
```

Result:

```
       Person     Clerk    month     run_
Obs      ID        ID       INT     length    flag

  1    123456    789415       1        1        0
  2    123456    789415       2        2        0
  3    123456    789415       3        3        0
  4    123456    789415       4        4        1
  5    123456    789415       6        1        0
  6    123456    789415       8        1        0
  7    123456    789415      10        1        0
  8    123456    789415      11        2        0
  9    123456    789415      12        3        0
 10    123456    789415      13        4        1
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Thank you for sharing your time and skills.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQL` to obtain the desired result set via a self join.

The join criteria `self.monthInt between each.monthId and each.monthId-3` finds candidates of 4 month intervals, and the having criteria `count (distinct each.monthInt) = 4` ensures an interaction in each month in the candidate interval.

```
select self.PersonId, self.ClerkID, max(self.monthInt) as monthOf4thInteraction
from 
  have as self
join 
  have as each
on 
  self.PersonId = each.PersonId and
  self.ClerkId = each.ClerkId and
  self.monthInt between each.monthId and each.monthId-3
group by 
  self.PersonId, self.ClerkId, self.monthInt
having count (distinct each.monthId) = 4
```

Comment: Thank you! This, as is the one above, is a perfect solution and , coming from a SQL background; it resonates.